# Can anybody tell me what this means?

Tags: translation, meaning, learning, chinese, calligraphy

[image: Ornament]
 I have an ornament, the picture, and I do not know what it means. I'm not even sure if it's Japanese but any help would be gladly taken.

Comment: I'm coming up with a near hit on 祿, but that doesn't quite hit the mark in my opinion.  It's got 示 on the left and 水 on the bottom right.  It's the top right that's throwing me off here...

Comment: 禄 roku is the salary for samurai warriors in the feudal era.

Comment: There were 元禄 genroku years in the Edo Tokugawa shogunate.

Comment: 禄/祿 >>> http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%A5%BF Wiktionary says it also means blessing, prosperity, happiness...

Comment: Transcription requests aren't allowed on this site, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

After looking at [this](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%A5%BF) and using rikaikun (Chrome Extension):

[image]

Looking it up in Tagaini Jisho gives me the ろく entry, but the top-right radical is written differently, even though one of the listed components is "彑". (A variant of 彑 is 彐 or ⺕).

[image]

It appears to be a kanji character that's used sparingly in Japanese, probably 人名用漢字 (JinmeiyouKanji) (Kanji used for names), but the image you gave shows an unsimplified version.

Comment: Ninja eyes! good job. I wonder why @chocolate didn't write an answer lol